# searching through XML via JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, xml, xslt, search

I'm trying to build a basic search engine using an XML document as a database. As of now, I have the following Jquery code loading the full XML into HTML format, but I want it to display the data based on user input (hence the search engine). How do I edit the following code so that the data is displayed based on user-defined variables?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "cbo_list.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(xml) {
                    var Counter = 0;
                    $(xml).find('cbo').each(function(){

                        var cboID = $(this).find('cbo_id').text();
                        var cboName = $(this).find('cbo_name').text();
                        var cboAddress = $(this).find('cbo_address').text();
                        var cboCity = $(this).find('cbo_city').text();
                        var cboState = $(this).find('cbo_state').text();
                        var cboZip = $(this).find('cbo_zip').text();
                        var cboDisplayName = cboName;
                        if (cboName.length >= 30) {
                            cboDisplayName = cboName.substring(0, 30) + '...';
                        }



                            $('<div class="items" id="link_' + cboID +'"></div>').html('<a href="cboDetail.html?cboID=' + cboID + '">' + cboDisplayName + '</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                            $('<div class="cboAddress"></div>').html(cboAddress).appendTo('#page-wrap');
                            $('<div class="cboAddress"></div>').html(cboCity + ', ' + cboState + '. ' + cboZip).appendTo('#page-wrap');
                            $('<hr>').html('<hr>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                        //}
                    });
                }
            });
        }); 

    function SettingsForm() {
        document.location = 'settings.html';
    }
```

As a side note; I originally tried doing this with XSL (...yeah...). Is it possible to combine the two? If so, how do I get around the fact that XSL is basically incapable of returning approximate matches?

Comment: What have you tryed in xslt?

Comment: @Kim; the XSLT code was just a for-each predicate stating cbo_list/cbo[node()=$CBO], where CBO is the user-input variable.